# Unable to create ECS Instance in Dubai Region?

Tags: alibaba-cloud

I am trying to create a server in UAE(Dubai) region but unable to do so. I am facing below error. What might be the issue?

[image: ECS Dubai Error]

It says

> "Don't have enough private IP's in this switch".

What is the allowed limit for private IP's under a switch and should I have to create one now?

Any help is appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://error-center.alibabacloud.com/status/product/Ecs

Refer to this section, your error code is QuotaExceeded.PrivateIpAddress and the solution is "You cannot create any more private IP address. Switch to another VSwitch and try again."

Answer (score 0):

Number of available private IP addresses depends on the private CIDR blocks.

When you create a VPC or a VSwitch, you must have specified the private IP address range in the form of a CIDR block.

Refer the complete documentation of VPC (Virtual Private Cloud):
https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/34217.htm

Also refer: VPCs and VSwitches:
https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/100380.htm